# Count DIFFDATE Exceeding A Specified Value - Step 2

Tags: sql

Further to my earlier question.  Now I have two different queries that work.  The first query returns a result of 5092 and the second returns a result of 1885 adding up to 6977.  I would like to combine them into one query to return a result of 6977.  How can I make one query count the number of conditionassessmentdates that are active, overdue by more than 14 days and null (counts as overdue)?  Thanks in advance.

```
select count (*)
from task_conditionassessment t
    inner join taskitems_conditionassessment ti on
        t.task_conditionassessmentguid=ti.task_conditionassessmentguid  
    inner join conditionassessmentassignmentitem c on
        ti.taskitems_conditionassessmentid=c.taskitems_conditionassessmentid
where datediff(dd,c.conditionassessmentdate,t.nextduedate)>14 and t.isactive=1


select t.taskname,t.nextduedate,c.conditionassessmentdate
from task_conditionassessment t
    inner join taskitems_conditionassessment ti on
        t.task_conditionassessmentguid=ti.task_conditionassessmentguid
    inner join conditionassessmentassignmentitem c on
        ti.taskitems_conditionassessmentid=c.taskitems_conditionassessmentid
where c.conditionassessmentdate IS NULL and t.isactive=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a count of records that fit either set of criteria, just use an `or` in your `where` clause:

```
select count (*)
from task_conditionassessment t
inner join taskitems_conditionassessment ti on
    t.task_conditionassessmentguid=ti.task_conditionassessmentguid  
inner join conditionassessmentassignmentitem c on
    ti.taskitems_conditionassessmentid=c.taskitems_conditionassessmentid
where (c.conditionassessmentdate IS NULL or
       datediff(dd,c.conditionassessmentdate,t.nextduedate)>14) and
      t.isactive=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing that I understand correctly, just `OR` the two conditions together:

```
select count (*)
from task_conditionassessment t
    inner join taskitems_conditionassessment ti on t.task_conditionassessmentguid=ti.task_conditionassessmentguid
    inner join conditionassessmentassignmentitem c on ti.taskitems_conditionassessmentid=c.taskitems_conditionassessmentid
where (datediff(dd,c.conditionassessmentdate,t.nextduedate)>14
        or c.conditionassessmentdate IS NULL)
    and t.isactive=1
```